# How do I forcibly obtain a domain?

Tags: domain-registration

I would like to acquire a domain name which is currently completely unused except to redirect to an unrelated domain's website. I have performed several port scans and the only active port is 80 which promptly sends a 302 on HTTP Get.

The site may be held by a domain squatter. How can I force them to give up the site? It is, for all intents and purposes, unused.

If it is registered to a domain squatter, how can I make it expensive for them to keep?

Comment: It's a shame this question was closed since it's answerable but now I can't answer it! If you have a trademark that is the same or close to the domain (common law is ok), and the first use in commerce of the mark predates the registration of the domain, and the domain was purchased primarily to sell back to the trademark owner at a profit, then you can file a UDRP dispute (mandatory arbitration) and it costs about $1,500 to file. I did it and won, but you have to know what you're doing since you only get one shot. A lawyer would charge about $7k to do this for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you know that they're not using it? Perhaps they are using it for their internal Active Directory domain, which recommends in one scenario using a purchased, but un-used, registered domain name.

Perhaps it is used for staging purposes internally.

Perhaps the domain is tied up in a VC funding round and and is awaiting trademark registration and they don't want to run the risk of using the domain while the trademark is pending.

I'm not a lawyer, but I believe the only case you have is if they are infringing on your trademark. You may be able to launch a trademark infringement case against them to claim a domain name. But this has mixed success in the United States. See [nissan.com](http://nissan.com/) or on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nissan_Motors_vs._Nissan_Computer).

I had a similar situation a while back. A 5-letter `.com` domain name that matched our registered trademark exactly. I checked the [Wayback Machine](http://archive.org/web/), saw that it was just personal domain in the late 90's and redirected to an IT provider now. I contacted the IT provider, and he explained that his client released the domain in the early 2000's but he had just held onto it.

We negotiated on a price over the next 2 months and settled on a very, very reasonable sum that was approximately 1/3 of which he had originally asked for the domain.

If you approach politely and with patience, you never know what you might get.

Comment: I honestly do not see where he even mentions the information regarding trademark in his question, yet your answer is very useful also.

Comment: @Traven he doesn't mention trademarks. I bring it up specifically because he does not mention it, so I don't believe he has a trademark claim. No trademark claim == no legal recourse.

Comment: I had already researched the trademark angle. As I did not have trademark *before* they registered the domain, there is no option for trademark recourse. That being said, I would like to think that there is some recourse against a registrant which isn't using it, even to host a domain.

Comment: @KG6ZVP - actually you can claim for a prior trademark infringement post-registration. But you need to have good lawyers and lots of money.

Comment: And there is no recourse. It's one of the weaknesses of the domain registration system, but also one of its strengths.

Comment: Actually, you don't need a lot of money or lawyers. We used our name in magazine ads in 1995. The domain was registered by a squatter in 2001. We got our federal trademark registration in 2011, and then won a UDRP for the name in 2012. It's first (provable) use in commerce that matters, not the date of the registration. I'm not a lawyer, and the UDRP fee was $1,500. The squatters wanted $8,000 for the domain. They didn't get a dime.

Answer (score 0):

If they hold the registration of the domain, you can not do anything about it, because they own the rights of the domain and what they are using it for, regardless if it is a redirect or being used for a website. It is their choice. There is nothing you can do about it till the registration period is up or they give up the rights to the domain.

Easy summary: They own it. They going to do as they please with it. Period.